# wrapping document.createElement() with custom type

Tags: javascript, wrapper

I want to make a viewport type that basically wraps a `<div>` tag with some custom styling options, but I'm not sure how to add the elements methods to my viewport type, I am trying something like this:

```
var viewport = function(){
    document.createElement.call(this, 'div');
    // additional custom properties...
    this.customStuff = ExtraProperty;
}

//would this work?
viewport.prototype = Object.create(document.createElement.prototype);

// additional custom methods...
viewport.prototype.constructor = viewport;
```

I want my viewport objects to be able to be used just like a Element object. So I could call like this:

```
var myVP = new viewport();
myVP.appendChild(someotherElementType);
```

I'm just not sure how to wrap document.createElement properly/effectively as I'm not sure where the .appendChild and other methods live etc. If it were used like a typical constructor I know I could use the pattern above but as you don't need to write `new document.createElement('type');` I'm not sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `document.createElement` should always be executed in the context of a document. Using `.call` or `.apply` does not make sense here.
2. Elements created using `document.createElement` do **not** inherit from `document.createElement.prototype` (it's not even a constructor!). DOM elements are implementing *interfaces*. When a method/property is both defined on `Node` and `Element`, then the one from `Element` takes precedence. In general, this should be the order of "inheritance":
   [Node](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247) > [Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-745549614) > [HTMLElement](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#htmlelement) > HTML*Name*Element.

When you want to add a custom property, extend one of these prototypes, e.g.

```
Node.prototype.foo = 1;
console.log(document.createElement('div').foo); //"1"
```

But these cannot be used as a constructor:

```
new HTMLDivElement; // TypeError: HTMLDivElement.prototype is not a constructor
Object.create(HTMLLIElement).innerHTML; // undefined
Object.create(HTMLAnchorElement).href ; // undefined
```

But you cannot create custom elements by defining a global HTML*Name*Element object:

```
window.HTMLHelloElement = HTMLDivElement; // Expected: Create alias for div
document.createElement('hello');          // Result: [object HTMLUnknownElement]
```

Compatibility:

- IE 7- does not expose any inheritable prototype
- IE8: Elements only inherit from `Element.prototype`.
- IE9+ / Chrome 1+ / Firefox 1+ / Opera 8+ / Safari 3+: Follows the standard.

---

> "I want to make a viewport type that basically wraps a  tag with some custom styling options"

Class names and CSS are more suitable for defining class-specific styles. For example:

```
var foo = document.createElement('div');
foo.className = 'type-viewport';       // CSS style sheet: .type-viewport { ... }
```